# I can't convert ui to py

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have been stuck on this problem for a week now. I have tried every single method I have found but it still doesn't work.

I wrote:

```
pyuic5 -o untitled.ui test.py
```

That gave me an `is not recognized` error.

Then I tried to specify the full path to the bat file. That simply gives me an invalid syntax error.

I literally have nothing left to try now and Stackoverflow is my last shot. Why couldn't they just fix the "show code" in the QtDesigner itself? Would of been so much easier.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Hey, swap your arguments :) `pyuic5 -o test.py untitled.ui`

Comment: You wasted a whole week, when you could have just run `pyuic5 --help`, or checked the [pyuic5 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#pyuic5), to see where you were going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is incorrect. -o reffers to the output. Since .ui is the input, pyuic gets confused and throws an error. Try doing this:

```
pyuic5 -o pythonFile.py uiFile.ui
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\Python36\Scripts>pyuic5 -x path\filename.ui -o path\filename.py
```